# RMarkdown blank space show up as black question mark

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I have R markdown generated html document that looks fine on my computer, but when I open the same document on another computer, all the spaces and special characters showed up as question marks (see below). Does anyone know why is this happenning?

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Make sure your script has the correct encoding (UTF-8?).

Comment: I inspected the document, and all the empty spaces are coded as &nbsp; as expected. I am confused at why it works on one computer and not the other. Both computers are windows and using chrome for both computers. Could it be an issue with an older version of chrome?

Comment: Can you post a  [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)? (I.e. a minimal .Rmd *and* the resulting .html that reproduces the problem? Should only be a few lines of code)